# SQL Trigger for comparing on insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'd like to write a trigger that checks top value in column (table consists of 4 double columns and one of them acts as a primary key (value within that field should always be bigger then previous entry)). Now is there a way to compare a top value of id column with new value that should be inserted, and rollback transaction if value of new id is equal or lower then previous top value(by using sql triggers of course).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: This sounds like an idiosyncratic and fragile design, to make a double rather than an integer be the primary key and to try to make it act something like an autoincrementing value or sequence. But your trigger would simply require the next ID to be greater than MAX(yourDoublePrimaryKeyValue).

Comment: Why won't a sequence or autoincrement field do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One and most easy way I found is to check if you get any result. I mean this:

```
if (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name WHERE id = id_you_want_check >= 1) {
    rollback;
}
```

If you know to use triggers in mysql or whatever DBMS you are using (look at the documentation of your DBMS).

PS: As said Colin, next time post your SQL DBMS to easily find an appropiate solution for you. **;)**

Comment: The proposed solution only tests whether the PK value is already in use. OP wants the new id to be greater than the max ID in use.

Comment: Then he should change `SELECT COUNT(*)` with `SELECT MAX(pk)`. Like this: `if (SELECT MAX(pk) FROM tbl_name == id_you_want_check)...` Sorry for my missunderstanding.